# Wireless keyboard & mouse receiver only recognized as a mouse receiver (Rpi 4 ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: wireless, ubuntu, keyboard, mouse

I have a USB receiver that's for both a keyboard and a mouse. When I plug it in to a computer, it works perfectly.

But when I plug it in to my raspberry pi 4, the wireless keyboard doesn't work while the mouse works. The weirdest thing is that when I plug in a wired keyboard, the wireless keyboard works as well. This is an inconvenient solution since the wired keyboard is power-hungry.

Is there a way to tell my raspberry pi that the receiver is for both a keyboard and a mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I have a pi4 that is behaving exactly like what you described after upgrading from 20.04 to Ubunth 21.04 (logitech wifi keyboard + mouse pad combo).

Below solution from https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=310293#p1889485 worked for me.

- either...

  - ssh in
  - find a physical keyboard
  - "at the gdm3 login screen use the gear icon at bottom right to select Gnome Xorg Session" then open a terminal.
- run the below:

```
sudo -s
echo "blacklist hid_logitech_dj" >> /etc/modprobe.d/local-dontload.conf
echo "install hid_logitech_dj /bin/false" >> /etc/modprobe.d/local-dontload.conf
depmod -a
update-initramfs -u

reboot now
```